# Python watchdog usage that ignores hidden files in any directory

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I have a use of Watchdog that I thought would ignore events concerning hidden files in any directory:

```
class MyHandler(RegexMatchingEventHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyHandler, self).__init__(ignore_regexes=["^\..*", ".*/\..*"])

    def on_modified(self, event):
        print("on_modified: " + event.src_path)

    def on_created(self, event):
        print("on_created: " + event.src_path)
```

It doesn't though as on_modified and on_created are still called for hidden files in subdirectories. Hidden files in the top level directory are excluded, which is good. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't have to escape "/" BTW. And are you running windows by chance? because paths use \ not /

Comment: My bad. But, I removed the \ char, and it's the same. And no, not on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found and I think should work to ignore hidden files in main directory and its sub-dir.

```
super(MyHandler, self).__init__(ignore_regexes=['^[.]{1}.*', '.*/[.]{1}.*'])
```

Hope will help others!

Also Look for the class `PatternMatchingEventHandler` and how pattern can be passed.